# CSS Image Positioning (square)

Tags: html, css

I have 4 images on my website, I'm trying to position it so that they all form to make an equal square within my DIV however it's coming out like a vertical line of 4 images. I want it appear like 2 vertical lines of 2 images next to each other making it a square with 4 images. Please advise how I would achieve this.

```
 <div id="main-content" class="group">
     <img src="mg.jpg" title="MG" alt="Car" style="max-width:50%;
 max-height:50%;">
     <img src="4x4.jpg" title="MG" alt="Car" style="max-width:50%;
 max-height:50%;">
     <img src="audi.jpg" title="MG" alt="Car" style="max-width:50%;
 max-height:50%;">
     <img src="ford.jpg" title="MG" alt="Car" style="max-width:50%;
 max-height:50%;">
 </div>


 #main-content {
    max-width:1000px;
    width:66.6667%; 
    float:right;
    min-height:1000px;
    height:100%;
    color:white;
    background-color: #0D3D56;
 }
```

**Notes:** The reason the width is set to 66.6667% is because there is another div on the same page covering the rest of the width.

I'm making this site with responsive design.

Comment: Do you want 2 columns and 2 rows? 2 x 2?

Comment: second image says 4x4, no, why not using just 2 extra divs?

Comment: @halfbit  the 4x4.jpg is the name of the jpg file, its a picture of a 4x4 car lol, but i will try your extra div method now

Comment: @MaihanNijat yes you are right! the correct terminology!

Comment: since - I think - you want to have squares, you mean same height and width - so your images should also be squares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rytgs1o/)
First I cleaned up a few general errors. For example your img tags should look like 
`<img src=""/>` 
with a slash. Then I created css to tell all the images to be half of the div's width and height.

```
<div id="main-content" class="group">
   <img src="mg.jpg" title="MG" alt="MG"/>
   <img src="4x4.jpg" title="4x4" alt="4x4"/>
   <img src="audi.jpg" title="Audi" alt="Audi"/>
   <img src="ford.jpg" title="Ford" alt="Ford"/>
 </div>

 #main-content {
   width:66.67%;
   float:right;
   min-height:1000px;
   height:100%;
   color:white;
   background-color: #0D3D56;
 }
 img {
   float:left;
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: you have overseen the 2/3 in width

Comment: ah, its here now, but missing in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I just edited the inline-style for images.

Use the following:

```css
#main-content {
 max-width:1000px;
 width:66.6667%; 
 float:right;
 min-height:1000px;
 height:100%;
 color:white;
 background-color: #0D3D56;
 }
```

```html
<div id="main-content" class="group">
 <img src="mg.jpg" title="MG" alt="Car" style="width:50%; max-width:50%; max-height:50%;" />
 <img src="4x4.jpg" title="MG" alt="Car" style="width:50%; max-width:50%; max-height:50%;" />
 <img src="audi.jpg" title="MG" alt="Car" style="width:50%; max-width:50%; max-height:50%;" />
 <img src="ford.jpg" title="MG" alt="Car" style="width:50%; max-width:50%; max-height:50%;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright easiest solution: 
 1. Go to getuikit.com and download that thing
 2. Link the corresponding CSS, js and jQuery.js (google it, you can download it from jQuery.com)
 3. Get an overall div for all 4 images and set its class as "uk-grid"
 4. Set the class of each image as "uk-width-medium-1-2", you can change the medium part to small or large based on your liking.
 5. ???
 6. Profit. You now have a set of image positioning that is responsive and will stack when you are looking at it on a smaller screen.